# Characters are turned in to question marks in strings.xml after building

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Initially the strings.xml file looks like this;

[image]

After android studio build it becomes like this;

[image]

I am running on 
Windows 10 version 1607 and 
Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Try to check that "Settings -> File Encodings" uses UTF-8

Comment: `After android studio build it becomes like this;`. So you had a perfect file. Well then i wonder what Android Studio had to build. It is pretty unclear what you did/do with that file to have that result.

Comment: When android studio launches it runs a Gradle build, this happens after that

Comment: Did a pair of experiments. Something like this is happening when I convert file encoding from utf-8 to any non-Unicode. "File -> File encoding". I can't change encoding of strings.xml though.

Comment: @Janak just remove top line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 1):

Android studio supports English by default, the question marks visible after build might be an after effect of the Android studio being unable to understand that language.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages) article of Android guidelines for supporting multiple languages.

Comment: Article is about Android, not Android Studio. OP has some problem with IDE IMO

Comment: yeah but maybe he could atleast try putting his strings.xml in different folder as mentioned, you never know

Comment: Nope. Cyrillic in default `values/strings.xml` is absolutely ok. I'm Russian and did it many times :)

Comment: The strings.xml files for each language are in their respective folders.